# What is this partially disassembled aircraft in the desert?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification

I found this plane on Google Earth. I'm guessing it is being deconstructed, as there are no factories nearby. What countries could it have originated from?

[image: plane]

The coordinates are 35°54'10.9"N, 117°43'51.6"W. Here's the [location on Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/35%C2%B054'10.9%22N+117%C2%B043'51.6%22W/@35.90296,-117.731147,151m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d35.9030167!4d-117.7309917).

The plane is about 41 feet long, and seems to have had a wingspan of about 30 feet.

Also, if it is possible, what kinds of planes could this be?

Sorry if this question is not really possible to answer. I'm a complete beginner at aircraft.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So, you found what looks like an [F-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vought_F-8_Crusader) missing a wing in the middle of the USN's Air Warfare Center at [China Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naval_Air_Weapons_Station_China_Lake).

It resembles the F-8 a lot:
[image]
[Image Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Chance_Vought_F8E.svg)

As @Andrew said in a comment, the plane might be an [F-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grumman_F-11_Tiger) which has a little closer resemblance to your picture.

[image]
[Image Source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1c/Grumman_F11F-1_Tiger_drawings.png)

Comment: Thanks! I wonder what they are doing with an airplane that was decommissioned 16 years ago

Comment: @MCMastery Probably seems like they are bombing it or something like that since it is an "Air Warfare Center".

Comment: I don't know what plane it is, but I'm skeptical of it being an F-8. Look at the horizontal stabilizer. The F-8 has almost a delta wing for a stabilizer, while the one in the image is more of a swept wing. The wing tips also don't look quite right, and the positioning of the canopy seems further back than on the F-8.

Comment: @BretCopeland Hmm, then it could be an F-100. But there are some parts that don't fit...It does not look that much of an A-7.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know. A little more plausible. It still doesn't look quite right to me, but at the same time, it's a really low resolution image of a damaged airplane, so it's hard to know what elements of the plane are real, and what are artifacts. For example, the two black dots on the fuselage above the wings, is that a real thing, or damage, or open panels, or artifacts?

Comment: @BretCopeland Looking at all the different images of planes, the F-8 seems the closest match.

Comment: I did a quick overlay of the F-8 with the image, and they just don't look like a match to me at all. Look at the sweep of the leading edge of both the wing and the horizontal stabilizer. They're simply not the same airplane. http://i.stack.imgur.com/MfJmM.png

Comment: There is always the possibility that google earth image is distorted.

Comment: It is definitely not an F-8. The F-8 has two wings.

Comment: F-11 not F-8? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grumman_F-11_Tiger#/media/File:Grumman_F11F-1_Tiger_drawings.png The fuselage seems to have the same shape, and the F-11 stabilisers look closer to what you have than those on the F-8.

Comment: [Overlay of the F-11 with the image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/45sa5.png). It's a perfect match, so the plane is/was almost certainly an F-11.

Comment: Another reason it's not an F-8 is the fact that you can clearly see the air intake ducts on the sides of the fuselage. The F-8 has a single air intake under the nose.

Answer (score 11):

Shape of the wing and stabilizers match F-11. (aka F11F) Layout of the fuselage: nose - cockpit - air intakes - tapering fuselage - wing - non tapering fuselage - horizontal stabilizers, match the F-11.

F-8 cockpit much further forward, has no lateral air intakes, horizontal stabilizer shape doesn't match. Gnat has a longer nose, no tapering fuselage ahead of the wing, too much taper on fuselage aft of wing. F-100 has no lateral air intakes.

What's it doing there? It's a simulated target. Photo, radar and electro-optical sensors, not to mention pilot eyes, can locate and identify it. The shipping containers look like shipping container or sand-bag revetments.

Comment: Thank you, this is a big reason I was asking the question - What is it doing there?

Answer (score -1):

It could possibly be the Folland Gnat.

[image]

Comment: The profile looks more like the accepted answer.

Comment: This seems extremely unlikely. The US military never used the Gnat, and the Gnat is considerably smaller than the plane pictured (29 long and 22ft wingspan, vs approx 40ft and 30ft). The Gnat tapers much more at its tail, and the wing joins the fuselage right behind the cockpit, whereas the pictured plane doesn't taper much at the tail and the cockpit seems to be a long way forward of the leading edge of the wing.